# CSS float ul lists and paragraphs

Tags: html, css, image, list, css-float

I tried to do this http://prntscr.com/cdbzsu but looks like I'm not so good with css float :(.

I tried to look on others tutorials but I still couldn't do it.

Please someone give some help.

This is what I did so far.

```css
.edit-text {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.edit-text p {
  width: 100%;
}
.edit-text ul {
  float: left;
}
.edit-text ul li {
  list-style: circle inside;
}
.edit-text img {
  float: right;
  width: 102px;
  height: 130px;
}
.edit-text a {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #002B0F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="edit-text">
  <p>Vous-voulez nous consulter pour vous aider à réviser votre vitrine commerciale?</p>
  <p>Ce service inclut: </p>
  <ul>
   <li>La révision</li>
   <li>La mise en page de la vitrine commerciale</li>
   <li>La correction et l’adaptation de mots clés pour le SEO</li>
   <li>Service payant</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" title="Click here">Cliquez ici pour envoyer la demande de consultation</a>
  <img src="http://www.holidaymood.com/images/ContactGirl.png" alt="Image">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your actual question/problem?

Comment: I can't arrange the text and photo like in the snapshot image

Comment: I have provided a snippet which better represents your question:Outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift your `img` above the `green` text and clear the float by using:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

after the `img` tag and I think you can move it forward from here. Cheers!

```css
.edit-text {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.edit-text p {
  width: 100%;
}
.edit-text ul {
  float: left;
}
.edit-text ul li {
  list-style: circle inside;
}
.edit-text img {
  float: right;
  width: 102px;
  height: 130px;
}
.edit-text a {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #002B0F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="edit-text">
  <p>Vous-voulez nous consulter pour vous aider à réviser votre vitrine commerciale?</p>
  <p>Ce service inclut: </p>
  <ul>
   <li>La révision</li>
   <li>La mise en page de la vitrine commerciale</li>
   <li>La correction et l’adaptation de mots clés pour le SEO</li>
   <li>Service payant</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="http://www.holidaymood.com/images/ContactGirl.png" alt="Image">
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <a href="#" title="Click here">Cliquez ici pour envoyer la demande de consultation</a>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although this solution works, The image is not aligned properly compared to the image he provided for his outcome, and the clickable link is not aligned either. The easiest way is to do it the way i shown below.

Comment: @Ricky the question is about handling floats... if you have downvoted me, that's sad :(

Comment: Yes his question is about floats, Because he is going about it the wrong way, He is trying to achieve his "Wanted Outcome" using Floats, which will will not work in an alignment sense, for his Outcome. His screenshot of how he wants it to look. With your reputation i would have thought you would have been focused on his wanted outcome. Which is what initiated the question in the first place. It probably isn't his fault that he is going about it the wrong way, you could of at least put an attempt to "Help" the person and not just "Answer the Question" which wont help him in the long run.

Comment: in that case you should be commenting on the question and let OP know about that... you should talk with OP and convince him that my answer should not be accepted, you should not be telling me this I guess :D

Comment: I have sent him an edit request, It is upto him to accept or not, And you said i was Sad for downvoting you....

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution to get it to look exactly how you portrayed on that image (minus the red writing). Took the liberty of providing a codepen for you.

http://codepen.io/Ballard/pen/ambGQA

Although Kukkuz answer seems to resolve what you are trying to do, It involves specifying the style in the HTML exactly, rather than using it on your CSS sheet, you will also have problems trying to align the image and the clickable link properly. Have a look at my snippet below, for an easier better solution.

```css
.edit-text {
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 490px;
  background-image: url(http://www.holidaymood.com/images/ContactGirl.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 350px 40px;
  background-size: 100px 115px;
}
.edit-text p {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.edit-text ul li {
  list-style: circle inside;
}
.edit-text a {
  background-color: #002B0F;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="edit-text">
  <p>Vous-voulez nous consulter pour vous aider à réviser votre vitrine commerciale?</p>
  <p>Ce service inclut: </p>
  <ul>
   <li>La révision</li>
   <li>La mise en page de la vitrine commerciale</li>
   <li>La correction et l’adaptation de mots clés pour le SEO</li>
   <li>Service payant</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" title="Click here">Cliquez ici pour envoyer la demande de consultation</a>
 </div>
```